# How to scroll height of image inside a grid when object-ft: cover and object-position: center top

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, object-fit

I have created an image gallery using flex. The images are columns where the width of each image is adjusted so that the gallery fits the width of the flex container. When a user hovers over an image in the gallery the image grows and shows its full size.

The images are set to object-fit: cover and object-position: center top, as this prevents the images from scaling to fit the height of the flex container and the top of the image is displayed on hover.

However, I would like the user to be able to scroll the height of the image after it has been expanded if the image has a vertical overflow.

Has anyone encountered this before and do you have any advice for what I should do to achieve this objective?

My HTML and CSS is as follows:

Create the image gallery

```
 <section class="portfolio_gallery">

            <div class="portfolio_columns">
                <img class="portfolio_image" src="./Resources/images/bluepinkandwhite.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio_columns">
                <img class="portfolio_image" src="./Resources/images/image2.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio_columns">
                <img class="portfolio_image" src="./Resources/images/image3.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio_columns">
                <img class="portfolio_image" src="./Resources/images/image4.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>

        </section>
```

.portfolio_gallery is flex with the width of my wrapper

```
.portfolio_gallery {
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  max-width: 70vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

.portfolio_columns are also flex

```
.portfolio_columns {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

when a user hovers over an image it grows to show the whole image

```
.portfolio_columns:hover {
  flex-grow: 4;
}
```

the images (.portfolio_image) inside the gallery are set to object-fit: cover with object-position: center top

```
.portfolio_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `overflow-y: auto` in your hover class and on the image you need to set the **height to auto** on hover. Here is the final solution.

```
.portfolio_columns:hover {
  flex-grow: 4;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.portfolio_columns:hover .portfolio_image {
  height: auto;

}
```

Edited to fix the image height transitions and cutting of the image use the following:

```
.portfolio_columns:hover .portfolio_image {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Link to my code pen final result: https://codepen.io/shivakumarjakkani/pen/RwVGqbx

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! Is there any way to hide the vertical scroll bar while still allowing vertical scrolling?

Comment: You can use scrollbar-with, and track properties to hide the scrollbar. Be very cautious as not all browsers support this feature. You can follow the medium link [Scrollbar hide](https://medium.com/frontend-development-with-js/how-to-hide-scrollbar-and-visible-only-scrolling-79cc3472e503)

Comment: Upon testing - this cuts off the top of the image and places the top of the image above the highest range of the scroll. Also when the user hovers over the image the height reduces and then increases creating an unwanted animation.

Comment: In terms of hiding the scrollbar your solution hides global scrollbars instead of just the scrollbar of the gallery image. I just need to hide the scrollbar for the image.

Comment: @JessicaRyan, you can apply the scrollbar-width property to the porfolio-columns class, then it will hide the scrollbar of that div. You can checkout the same also in my codepen link.

Comment: thanks. In the end, I just styled it using: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Shiva Kumar's answer I did the following:

```
.portfolio_columns:hover {
  flex-grow: 4;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.portfolio_columns:hover .portfolio_image {
  height: auto;
  align-self: start;
}
```